# Designing an efficient database for logging data

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am designing a database for a project I am working on. I have 3 tasks (which the user can choose from)

- First task gives 10 questions
- Second task gives 20 questions
- Third task gives 30 questions

*n.b. the accuracy of the test result will increase as the number of questions go up*.

For each question, there are going to be two answers. `Answer 1` and `Answer 2`. So if there are 10 questions, there are going to be total of 20 answers logged.

What I have designed so far is a `user` table and a `test_result` table. The `test_result` table is the part I am having trouble designing.

The `user` table has the following attributes

- user id
- name
- registration date

The `test_result` table has the following attributes

- test id
- user id (references user ID in user)
- test taken time

My problem is I do not know how I am going to efficiently log 10~30 question answers.

I am considering using a `test_result` table

The `test_result` table would have the following attributes

- test id
- user id
- test taken time
- answer 1a
- answer 1b
- answer 2a
- answer 2b
- ...
- answer 60a
- answer 60b**

but I think there should be a more efficient way.

**EDIT:**

To clarify...

Each question will record 2 different answers.

- Question 1 will have Ans1 Ans2.
- Question 2 will have Ans1 Ans2.
- etc..

all the way up to 10~30 questions (the number of questions varies depending on the task you chose)

**----::EDIT 2::**

OK... SO I have come up with an improved design but I am still struggling.

It looks like :

`User` (user_id, Name, reg_date)

`Test` (test_id, type [either 1,2,3], category [there are 5 different categories] )

`Response` (Response_id, user_id, test_id, response_date, response_1a, response_1b, response_2a, response_2b, ... , response_30a, response_30b)

But again, I run in to the problem of having +120 columns for the `Response` table. Each responses will be numeric values from 0~1.0.

Notice that if the `test_id` is 1, there would be only 10 questions, so the columns in `Response` table from `response_11a` to `response_30b` would be `null`.

An example record would be:

`Response` (1, 1, 1, 2015/04/30, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, ... (a lot of records)...  , 1.0, 0.3, null, null, null, (all nulls because there are only 10 questions for test_id 1. ) )

I cannot think of another way of doing this. :/

Is this a good way of designing the database?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement in short is,

A **user** can complete **tests**. Each **test** can be made up of *10, 20 or 30* **questions**. Each **question** has exactly *two* **choices**. **Questions** are **answered** by **users**.

So you get

- `user (id, name, reg_date)`
- `test (id, name)`
- `question (id, test_id, text, choice1, choice2)`
- `answer (id, question_id, user_id, choice, answer_date)`

Or you could do

- `user (id, name, reg_date)`
- `test (id, name)`
- `question (id, test_id, text)`
- `choice (id, question_id, value, label)`
- `answer (id, question_id, user_id, choice_id, answer_date)`

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but for my purpose, the question and answer table would not work. The question table assumes that each question has 2 SET choices, but this isn't the case.

Comment: SAME Question is given to the person 10~30 times (but the question changes a bit every time),  and depending on the user's response, the answer would vary.

Comment: The answer is , rather than it being A or B, it's a number from 0~1.0 .

Answer (score 0):

Seems a good start given there's always an a & a B

```
TestAnswers(ID, TestID, AnswerA, AnswerB)
```

That said it's far from clear which answer goes with which question...

Comment: So each question will record 2 different answers.